# Multiple Forms and Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am design in a Quiz s/w where in Questions are laid out in form of a Question paper. The user supposes to answer exactly only one question and only one answer. My problem is that for every question and 3 options I have different Forms. Once i submit, i wanna know which radio button is checked in the various form get submitted. The code is something like this.

```
<html>
<form name="one" action="me.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name=" subject " value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form name="one" action="me2.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name=" subject " value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="one" action="me3.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name=" subject " value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="one" action="me4.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options" value="some thing">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: why are you taking multi forms ?

Comment: have a go with `isset()`.

Comment: btw, watch the spaces in `name=" subject "` they count as spaces.

Comment: Thank you for identifying a space character.

Comment: my requirement is "The user supposes to answer exactly only one question and only one answer" and every question response is send to separate pages for performing other computations.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple forms, do like this,

```
<html>
<form name="one" action="me.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="subject_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">


<input type="radio" name="subject_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">
<input type="radio" name="options_dbid" value="some thing">


<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

where `dbid` is your database.

Make sure, `dbid` is the id of your question.(this should be same for subject as well as options.)

For first question your post will have, `subject_1` and `option_1` will have the selected for the question.

To access the questions and answers in php, use `explode()` with `_` in php.

`$arr[1]` will have the database id. You can match the answer with database easily.

Comment: Thank you Sir. My requirement is "The user supposes to answer exactly only one question and only one answer" and every question response is send to separate pages for performing other computations

Comment: at a time you will display only 1 question??